# How to extract Raw of TCP packet using Scapy

Tags: python, hex, extract, scapy

I use the `sniff` function of scapy module. My `filter` and `prn` function are doing a great job. But now, I would like to extract the `Raw` of the `TCP packet` and handle it using hexadecimal or binary format.

Here is the [documentation](http://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.2.0/classscapy_1_1packet_1_1Packet.html) of Packet Class in scapy.

How can I do that ?

I tried `print packet[Raw]` but it seems to be converted as ASCII or something like that. I want to keep it in hexadecimal or binary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the raw bytes of the packet using [`scapy.compat.raw`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.compat.html#scapy.compat.raw)<sup>1</sup>:

```
from scapy.all import raw
raw(packet)
```

The former is cross-version compatible, but if you are guaranteed to run with *Python 3* and support for *Python 2* is not needed, you can simply invoke `bytes`, which doesn't require an ad-hoc import statement (and is actually how `scapy.compat.raw` is [implemented](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/compat.py#L274) behind the scenes):

```
bytes(packet)
```

---

You can print the raw bytes of the packet in a readable format using [`scapy.compat.bytes_hex`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.compat.html#scapy.compat.bytes_hex)<sup>2</sup>:

```
from scapy.all import bytes_hex
print(bytes_hex(packet))
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> `scapy.compat.raw`'s implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/compat.py#L264).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> `scapy.compat.bytes_hex`'s implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/compat.py#L320).</sup>

Comment: This is outdated / the function doesn't exist anymore. In Python 3 it seems you can just call a `bytes(packet)`, no imports needed.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I've edited my answer to reflect the option to directly invoke `bytes(packet)` in _Python 3_. However, I do believe that `scapy.compat.raw` still [exists](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/compat.py#L264) and has the advantage of cross-version compatibility.