# How just get raw with scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scapy

For a project I use scapy to sniff my network and check some data.
But for seeing each frame, I use `.show()`, and I just want to see the raw part.

How can I do it?

```
packets = sniff('xx.xx.xx.xx')
packets.show()
```

Comment: Can you give the output that you're getting at the moment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract Raw of TCP packet using Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172789/how-to-extract-raw-of-tcp-packet-using-scapy)

Answer (score 0):

`packets` is a python list of `scapy.Packet`s, not a instance of `scapy.Packet`. If you want to use `show`, you need to run that function on an instance of `scapy.Packet`, i.e. `packets[0].show()`