# Using scapy.packet.raw

Tags: python, hex, scapy

I am sniffing packet with Scapy and I get the raw bytes:

```
 t = packet[TCP].payload
print(type(t))
```

type tells me that the content here is  and the output is:

> b'\x16\x03\x03\x01\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\xe2\xc9\x150\xc7\x92\x18\x8d\xf2~5x\xb2bU\xd0\xf2\x97\xe1\xc5\xc0na\x9f\x9d>Dnv\xa9X\xb18\r\x03\xdeuN8\xaf\xfb/\xd3^:\x1c\xd7\x984\xbbvn~8\x03\x16\t\x14'

I cannot use the binascii.hexlify, etc to convert this to hexadecimal because the data type is not string, int, or bytes.

Anyone have a solution to convert this to either bytes, hex string, something like this?

> 16030102

Comment: `print str(t).encode("HEX")`? returns a 142 character long alpha-numeric string; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172789/how-to-extract-raw-of-tcp-packet-using-scapy

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error: File "./pcapy.py", line 50, in packet_callback
    print(str(t).encode("hex"))
LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, and I can't reproduce your results. does `print(type(t))` give `b'\x16\x03\x03\x01\x...\x14'` output? what  does `print(t)` show?

Comment: type gives back: <class scapy.packet.raw>. I'm guessing the type is raw.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution which worked with scapy.packet.raw:

```
pkt = binascii.hexlify(bytes(packet[TCP].payload))
```

Now I can search the content simply:

```
if data[:4] == b'1603':
```

simple enough for what I need at the moment